# Which is better i3 with 4GB RAM or i5 with 2GB RAM?

Tags: laptop, memory, cpu

Can someone explain which will be better, laptop with core i3 processor, 4GB RAM OR core i5 processor, 2GB RAM ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends really on *which* generation processors, and what you use it for - do you need a specific extension that's in one and not the other (for example VT). I generally tend to find that, except in exceptional circumstances, i'm not actually using all my processor power, so the processor i use is less critical.

On the other hand, many modern OSes, including windows 7 uses spare ram for caching, so you might see a advantage there.

One would need a little more information for a definitive answer.

Answer (score 3):

Memory is a cheaper (and easier) upgrade than processor.

While I agree with the theory most of the other answers get into, I would purchase the i5 system and plan on upgrading the memory down the road if I find it is necessary.

It is highly unlikely that you are purchasing the computer for a static set of tasks. Rather you're looking for something that will do what you think it needs to do today, as well as for what you may come up with for it to do tomorrow, and the next day.

2GB memory is a good minimum. It's kinda like what 128MB of memory was 15 or so years ago. Unless you're running memory-intensive applications right away, you're probably going to get more immediate benefit from the i5 system with 2GB memory. And going forward, as mentioned above, this system will remain capable of more for a longer period of time for less money in upgrades than the i3 system.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information given, this is unanswerable.

However, if we were to assume a modern OS running under a standard workload, 4GB of memory would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Does the i5 laptop have empty memory banks or support a larger memory module? If yes, I'd go with that one since memory can be upgraded but CPUs can't. Otherwise, 2GB is quite minimal for Win7, and too small for Vista. Other OSs can survive with 2GB but the more applications you run simultaneously, the slower it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Going with the i5 cpu would be a better choice it's a faster cpu. On a laptop you can't upgrade or change the cpu you however with the ram you can. So if you went with the i3 you're some what downgrading your option. Ram is super cheap nowadays so it's really not a big deal also it comes down to what you're planning to do so unless you're going to do heavy video editing, music editing and gaming I go with the i5 if I were you. Basic word processing, surfing the net does not require much power so which ever one you decide to go with will do that seemlessly. So always ask yourself that question what i am going to use the computer for down the road remember one thing about laptop there's only 2 things that you can upgrade ram and hardrive that's it. Always think long term.